# Neo4j Community 2.2.1 extensions fail to load

Tags: neo4j

I recently installed the Community edition of Neo4j v2.2.1 and developed a simple unmanaged extension. I edited neo4j.properties and added:

org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.ferguson.sar.service=/sar

but I continue to receive an HTTP 404 when I try to access my extension at:

http://localhost:7474/sar/service/Get Product/1

Using the console, if I go to System -> Extensions, my extension is not listed. Does the community version not support extensions or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance for any and all relevant responses.

Earnie!

P.S. Here is the code snippet for my extension:

```
@Path("/service")
public class GetService {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetService.class);

private final GraphDatabaseService db;

public GetService(@Context final GraphDatabaseService db) {
    this.db = db;
}

@Path("/{name}/{version}")
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getService(@PathParam("name") final String name,     @PathParam("version") final Integer version) {
```

E!

Comment: Only managed extensions are listed in the extensions page of the neo4j admin. BTW you do not have an endpoint /sar/service/Get/Product/1

Comment: Is your extension listed at startup to be added by Jersey?
Where do you put your jar?
Could you share your jar?